# Oracle Decode Function - Dynamic Search

Tags: oracle

I have the following decode function, which contains hard coded values:

```
decode(s.manure_type,
                   'OA','Oats',
                   'V','Velvet Beans',
                   'O','Other',
                   'N','None',
                   'SW','Soya Beans Without Grains',
                   'SR','Sunn Hemp',
                   'C','Cowpeas',
                   'S','Soya Beans With Grains',
                   'F','Forage Sorghum',
                   'J','Jap Millet',
                   'G','Grazing Vetch') s_manure_type
```

I want the decode to be dynamic. All values are from another table. So is the initial expression from another table. Is there any possibility of getting the values of Oats,Velvet Beans,Other,None,Soya Beans Without Grains, Sunn Hemp, Cowpeas,Soya Beans With grains, Forage Sorghum, Jap Millet and Grazing Vetch from the database?

Answer (score 0):

But, then you wouldn't even need `DECODE` - it will be a `JOIN`, e.g.

```
select a.something,
       b.manure_name
from tab1 a join manure b on a.manure_type = b.manure_type
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have need "DECODE" , you can do like this:

```
create table prm (
id varchar2(2),
name varchar2(100));

insert into prm values ('OA','Oats');
insert into prm values ('V','Velvet Beans');

select v.name from manure_types s, prm v
where s.manure_type = v.id
```